# Play Framework "runProd" not accepting custom config file

Tags: playframework, configuration, sbt

I'm trying to run in "prod mode" on my local environment but it seems the "sbt runProd" command don't accept any custom config file.

For example, if I run in "dev mode" like this:

`sbt -Dconfig.file=conf\helloworld.conf run`

It works perfectly, no error.

If I change the `run` for `runProd` like this:

`sbt -Dconfig.file=conf\helloworld.conf runProd`

Then I receive an error about missing database settings. I usually receive this error when I forget to provide the custom .conf. By default, Play tries to use the `application.conf` config but in my case, this file is there but doesn't contain any information about the database.

Here is a part of the exception I receive:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.`

Is there something wrong in my `runProd` command line? It's supposed to be supported as described [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ProductionConfiguration#Specifying-an-alternate-configuration-file)

I already tried to use absolute path to the config file and it doesn't change anything.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try and run `sbt -J-Dconfig.file=conf\helloworld.conf runProd`?

Comment: @TomerShetah Will give it a try this week.

Comment: I receive an error: 
```
[error] Expected ';'
[error] '-J-Dconfig.file
[error]                 ^